# Как сделать просмотр страницы через админку?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Как сделать просмотр страницы через админку?

Есть ресурс documents и соответствующий контроллер:

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @documents = Document.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end

  def admin_index
    @documents = Document.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    render layout: "admin" 
  end  

  def show
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  end

  def admin_show
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
    render layout: "admin" 
  end  

  ....
  ....
end
```

есть 2 layouts:

```
application.html.erb, 
admin.html.erb
```

контроллер index выводит список документов в публичной части сайта(application.html.erb).
контроллер admin_index выводит список документов в закрытой части сайта(admin.html.erb).

в публичной части сайта я могу посмотреть любой документ, нажав на ссылку 'show':

```
<% @documents.each do |document| %>
    <%= document.title %>
    <%= link_to 'Show', document %>
<% end %>
```

проблема в том, что в закрытой части сайта у меня не получается посмотреть любой документ, нажав ссылку:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', document %>
```

меня перебрасывает на страницу конкретного документа, но layout: application.html.erb, а мне нужен layout: admin.html.erb

routes:

```
Testpager::Application.routes.draw do
  get "admin/index"
  resources :news, only: [:index, :show]

  resources :documents, only: [:index, :show, :destroy]

  get "contacts/index"
  get "services/index"
  get "index/index"
  get "admin/index"
  get "admin/documents" => 'documents#admin_index'
  get "admin/documents/:id" => 'documents#admin_show'

  root 'index#index'
end
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Хочу порекомендовать разделить текущий контроллер на два (app/controllers/documents_controller.rb и app/controllers/admin/documents_controller.rb).
 Этот подход даст несколько плюсов -- изолированное пространство имен для админской части, независимые пути, возможность задать layout для каждого контроллера:

```
# app/controllers/admin/documents_controller.rb
class Admin::DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'

  def index
  end
end

# app/controllers/documents_controller.rb 
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end


# routes
Testpager::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :documents, only: [:index, :show, :destroy]
  end

  resources :documents, only: [:index, :show, :destroy]
end   


# links
link_to "Show in public part", document_path(@document)
link_to "Show in admin part", admin_document_path(@document)
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
link_to "Show", controller: "documents", action: "admin_show", id: @document
```

А вообще почитайте [документацию к хелперу](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

Comment: так пробовал. вот что получил: No route matches {:action=>"admin_show", :controller=>"documents", :id=>nil}

Comment: @prozaik, судя по nil, у вас проблемы с выставленными переменными

Answer (score 0):

Великолепная статья: http://habrahabr.ru/post/136461/. Больше 2х лет делаю таким же образом по Иерархии контроллеров и пока не жалуюсь.